# How can I prevent horizontal scrolling with an element intentionally positioned off screen?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a menu that slides in from the right when a button is clicked. I currently it is set to

```
body, html {
     overflow-x: hidden;
}    
nav {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0px;
     right: -300px;
     width: 300px;
}
```

And when the button is clicked, it is supposed to animate the right position to `right: 0px;`.
Since I used the position, when I use `overflow-x: hidden;` it doesn't work. What can I do the fix this?

Comment: This works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/FnucZ/
What's the problem? Can you maybe provide a little more context? Thanks!

Comment: What code do you use to slide the nav in? EDIT: updated bearoplane's fiddle, and it works fine: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FnucZ/1/)

Comment: No such thing as 0px. If setting a pixel value to 0 do not include px.

Comment: @bearoplane this is what I have http://jsfiddle.net/45ZLs/2/.
EDIT: Nevermind, this works. It doesn't work on my site though, strange.